# translating deprecated RSPEC

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec3

I'm trying to translate some old rspec tests (v 2.1) to work with the newest version of rspec (3.1) and running into some trouble with this line...

What would `subject.should_receive(:damage).with(10)` be in v3.0 syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new syntax is as follows:

```
expect(subject).to receive(:damage).with(10)
```

For more information read [this article](http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/)